# Simple JQuery gallery but fade in fade out not working

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple JQuery gallery set up but I cannot get the large image to fade in and fade out.

I have seen the fadeIn()and fadeOut() functions and tried using them but they are clearly not being added to the right place.

Code is as follows:

HTML

```
    <div id="gallery">
        <div id="panel">
            <img id="largeImage" src="images/image_01_large.jpg" />
            <div id="description">1st image description</div>
        </div>

        <div id="thumbs">
            <img src="images/image_01_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" />
            <img src="images/image_02_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" />
            <img src="images/image_03_thumb.jpg" alt="3rd image description" />
            <img src="images/image_04_thumb.jpg" alt="4th image description" />
            <img src="images/image_05_thumb.jpg" alt="5th image description" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
    $('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
        $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
        $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
    });
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use `on` instead of delegate if your are using jquery 1.7+

```
 $('#thumbs').on('click','img', function(){
   ....
```

and make sure your event is your first argument

```
 .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```